# How do I determine a cricital point of an area functional?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curves

The orientated area $A(\gamma)$ of a regular closed plane curve $(\gamma, \tau)$ is defined as $$A(\gamma) :=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\tau \det (\gamma,\gamma')$$
Now how can I determine the cricital points of the area functional $$\mathcal A:\mathcal M_L \to \Bbb R, \gamma \mapsto \mathcal A(\gamma)$$ where $\mathcal M_L$ denotes the space of closed plane curves $(\gamma,\tau)$ with length $L \gt0$, i.e. $\mathcal M_L = \{(\gamma,\tau) \vert \int_0^\tau\vert\gamma'\vert=L\}$.

Any hints on how to start would be much appreciated. Or maybe just an explanation on how I have to interpret $\det (\gamma,\gamma')$.

Comment: Critical points are usually where the derivative is equal to $0$...

Comment: Yes I know, I just have no idea how I differentiate $A$ because I don't know how to interprete $\det(\gamma,\gamma')$..

Comment: Oh, well, that's quite unfortunate, because neither do I.  XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\det(a,b) = a^TJb$ where $J = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right]$.

Then the Euler-Lagrange equations of 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\tau \gamma^TJ\gamma' + \lambda(\|\gamma'\|-L/\tau)$$
are
$$J\gamma' - \frac{d}{d\tau}\left(-J\gamma + \lambda \frac{\gamma'}{\|\gamma'\|}\right)=0$$
$$2J\gamma' - \frac{\lambda}{\|\gamma'\|}(I-TT^T)\gamma''=0$$
where $T=\frac{\gamma'}{\|\gamma'\|}$.

Multiplying both sides by $J\gamma'$ gives
$$2\|\gamma'\|^2 = \frac{\lambda}{\|\gamma'\|} J\gamma' \cdot \gamma''$$
or
$$\kappa = \frac{J\gamma' \cdot \gamma''}{\|\gamma'\|^3} = \frac{2}{\lambda}$$
and $\gamma$ has constant curvature, and so is a circle of length $L$.

Comment: Thank you. I have various questions though, this solution is way too advanced for me to understand immediately.
How do we obtain $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\tau \gamma^TJ\gamma' + \lambda(\|\gamma'\|-L/\tau)$? I would appreciate it if you could explain every step more precisely on a less advanced level if time allows.

Comment: And embarassingly, I am not able to see where/what the critical points of $\mathcal A$ are..

Comment: Where did this question come from? Are you familiar with the calculus of variations?

Comment: Yes I do know the the theorem of calculus of variations (haven't worked much with it though). I found it here http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/SS14/DGI/ on the 4th paper.
We are supposed to understand all papers in preparation for the exam.

Comment: @Sigma The topics you will need to review are 1) the calculus of variations, and 2) the method of Lagrange multipliers. The former tells you how to find the critical points of functionals, and the latter is an enhancement that allows you to add constraints (such as your arc length constraint) to the functional. These topics are too involved to explain in a post on this site; I recommend looking up the relevant course notes and then asking specific questions about places you get stuck.

Comment: Okay thank you I will have a closer look on those topics tomorrow, much appreciated.